# Doubt in Sphere Sphere intersection

Tags: analytic-geometry, spheres

I am trying to understand the sphere-sphere intersection in http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Sphere/TwoSpheres/Intersection.htm

[image]

I have a doubt. Can you tell me is AB(diameter of common circle) is perpendicular to line joining centers? Even wolfram takes that common plane is perpendicular to line joining centers....(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html)

Kindly enlighten...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you tell me is AB(diameter of common circle) is perpendicular to
>   line joining centers?

The common circle is the solution of the system:
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r_1^2 \\
(x-d)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r_2^2
$$
Assuming $d > 0$, for the solution points $(x,y,z)$ we get the constraint
$$
-2xd+d^2=r_2^2-r_1^2 \iff \\
x 
= \frac{r_1^2 - r_2^2 + d^2}{2d} = x_m = \text{const}
$$
by subtracting the first from the second equation and solving for $x$, so we have a circle in the $y$-$z$-plane, perpendicular to the line which connects the two center points.

We would get the circle equation by substituting the above expression into the first circle equation and then sorting the constant terms to the right, getting at some equation $y^2 + z^2 = R^2$ together with $x=x_m$.

Comment: thank you Sir. I could now see it .. Even the theorem that radical plane is perpendicular to line joining centers also follow from this.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the line joining the centers is the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ because of the symmetry of  each circle.

Thus $AB$ is perpendicular to  the line joining the centers as well.

Comment: Sir that's what is  surprising me. can you pls elaborate? line joining centers can also be a slant line?

Comment: @anirudhb Who cares whether it's a "slant line"? The question is whether it's perpendicular to $AB.$ You can "slant" both of the lines if you like, but they'll still be perpendicular to each other. Can you imagine any way they would _not_ be?

Comment: @anirudhb Please draw the two dimensional graph yourself and notice that both centers are equi -distance from A and B.  That makes the line joining the centers to be perpendicular bisector of AB. You probably want to  complete the bottom part of the graph as well.

Comment: Sir i now understood. AB should be straight line. If slanted, can not make symmetry.

Comment: Good, thanks for your attention and understanding.